# Get List of Timezones with GMT offset

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, timezone, timezone-offset

Can someone help me in getting a list of timezones with GMT/UTC (I believe these are the same) offset like
(GMT+5:30) Asia/Kolkata.

Thank You

Comment: You mean you want to find [time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) that ***currently*** experience a certain UTC offset? Could you add some background information?

Comment: No I want to display all the timezone I get from pytz.all_timezones with the UTC offset as given in the example in my question @FObersteiner

Comment: Nope I didn't understand, Could you give me an example

Comment: Time zones don't have a singular offset.  They have one or more offsets.  Which offset is in effect is very dependent on which point in time you are asking about.  A list of time zones to offsets made based on "now" could look very different "tomorrow" or "last year".